# Adding Google Maps to project and retrive locatons from database using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

what i mean i have xml file retrieve the database i want it as xml file and has fields i want to display it on Google map like 'city,country,street,longitude,latitude' i want take values from  this fields and display it on google map.i want to display this map at page load event.the problem i can not know how retrieve the data  from xml file and pass it to map .

This is code behind,

```
void GetTableFromXMlData(string strResult)
{
    CreateTable();
    XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDataDoc.LoadXml(strResult);
    foreach (XmlNode n in xmlDataDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Property"))
    {
        DataRow dr = dtSearchResult.NewRow();
        dr["HotelID"] = n.Attributes["IDHotel"].Value;
        dr["HotelName"] = n.Attributes["Hotelname"].Value;

        dr["MinRate"] = n.Attributes["MinRate"].Value;
        dr["MaxRate"] = n.Attributes["MaxRate"].Value;
        dr["StarCategory"] = n.Attributes["StarCategory"].Value;
        dr["ImageIdentifier"] = n.Attributes["ImageIdentifier"].Value;
        dr["VPhotoPath"] = strVirtualPath + n.Attributes["ImageIdentifier"].Value + "_Exterior.jpg";
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in n)
            {
                switch (childNode.Name)
                {
                    case "GEOData":///----->>>> here this the data i want to display it in a map.
                        {
                            dr["CountryCode"] = childNode.Attributes["CountryCode"].Value;
                            dr["CityName"] = childNode.Attributes["City"].Value;
                            dr["CityID"] = childNode.Attributes["IDCity"].Value;
                            dr["Zip"] = childNode.Attributes["Zip"].Value;
                            dr["Street"] = childNode.Attributes["Street"].Value;
                            dr["Longitude"] = childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value;
                            dr["Latitude"] = childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Value;



                            break;
                        }
                    case "Distances":
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode cChildNode in childNode)
                            {
                                if (cChildNode.Attributes["Type"].Value == "1")
                                    dr["DistanceToCity"] = cChildNode.Attributes["Distance"].Value;
                                else
                                    dr["DistanceToAirPort"] = cChildNode.Attributes["Distance"].Value;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Descriptions":
                        {
                            dr["Descriptions"] = childNode.FirstChild.Attributes["Text"].Value;
                            ((Label)FindControl("lblHoDescription1")).Text = childNode.FirstChild.Attributes["Text"].Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Meals":
                        {
                            dr["MinimumMeals"] = childNode.Attributes["MinimumMeals"].Value;
                            break;
                        }
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
        dtSearchResult.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An [**example**](http://www.creare.co.uk/loading-google-map-markers-via-xml) that goes from xml to maps

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your data in XML format more than half of your work is done. What you need to do now is to play with Javascript a bit.

- You have to initialize the Google Maps using the `function initialise()`.
- Define the `mapsize` and `type` in `MapOption`.
- Create an instance of a `Geocoder` class & `infoWindow` class.
- Finally write the function to load markers where your markers are represented by a coordinate as a combination of Latitude and Longitude and the info window displaying the rest of the data like Street, Country Code, CityName, Zipcode.

For detailed explanation you can take a look at the same [tutorial](http://www.creare.co.uk/loading-google-map-markers-via-xml) larrp has posted.